# Symfony4 PrePersist does not fire

Tags: doctrine, symfony4

I am testing PrePersist and other events in Symfony4 and Doctrine.

Here is my controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use App\Entity\Contact;
class C00260CallbackController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/c00260/callback", name="c00260_callback")
     */
    public function index()
    // Callback statements are in the Entity definition
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $contact = new Contact();
        $contact->setName('Elodie');
        $contact->setEmail('elodie@email.com');
        //$contact->setTimestamp();
        $entityManager->persist($contact);
        $entityManager->flush();
                return $this->render('c00260_callback/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'C00260CallbackController',
        ]);
    }
}
```

and my Entity

```
<?php
namespace App\Entity;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ContactRepository")
 */
class Contact
{
    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function setTimestamp()
    {
        $this->timestamp = new date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        return $this;
        dumpx($this->timestamp);
    }
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $email;
    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

The table contact has all the required fields

id
name
email
timestamp

When I run the controller, I should get current Date and Time in the datetime filed, but not only nothing happens, but alos the setTimestamp function is not even called (when a put a bug in it, it is not seen at execution)

What do I have wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works very nice for me:

```php
    /**
     * Callback called every time you create a new object
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     * @return Response
     */
    public function prePersist()
    {
        if (empty($this->createdAt)) {
            $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
        }
    }
```

...and put it in your entity after the params

Answer (score 0):

Why do you make it this complicated, why not just set the default value for datetime in your entity constructor. This way every initialized Contact gets a date automatically, and you can always easily override it.

If you do not want that, then I'd recommend setting up an entity listener separately, otherwise your entity becomes too bloated, harder to maintain.

Hope I helped a bit, ask away if you've questions

Comment: Thanks, I know this.
But my problem in NOT to set the timestamp, but to TEST prePersist event handling.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you able to set timestamp in `__construct ()` method of your entity

```
__construct(){
$this->timestamp = new \Datetime();
```

}

Comment: Thanks, I know this.
But my problem in NOT to set the timestamp, but to TEST prePersist event handling.